# Windows Server, help viewing this local website from my cell

Tags: windows, server

I have a Winserver that’s viewable at http://172.16.xx.xxx in both Firefox, and Chrome on Windows 10.

I believe my firewall is fine, but I am happy to check if that's what's causing the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I am using a virtual machine, I was given a 172 address. This didn't seem to be accessible through the network.

Steps

1. Press control + E
2. Navigate to Network Adapter
3. Select Autodetect under Bridge Networking

This gave me a real IP address on the network, (192.xxx) and now it works!

Answer (score 0):

check your firewall by telnet to the port 80 if your host machine (Machine A) ip name is 172.2.0.1 you should telnet to that IP from the other computer (Machine B) from CMD.
from Machine B do this.

```
telnet 172.2.0.1 80
```

if you found telnet is not and internal or external command in CMD try [Following steps](https://www.technipages.com/windows-10-enable-telnet)
if its giving a error then there is a firewall issue.